# Write text between merged cells using phpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have this code from phpExel.

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->mergeCells('A1:I1');
```

This code creates some blank space between columns A1 to I1.
Just want to add text in the center blank space(A1:I1).

I am trying this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->mergeCells('A1:I1','add some text here...');
```

but this code does not work.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply write the text value that you want to the top-left cell in the merged cell range

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
    ->mergeCells('A1:I1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('A1')
    ->setValue('This is the text that I want to see in the merged cells');
```

**EDIT**

To centre the text, use

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

again, using the top-left cell of the range

Comment: Thank you  Mark,your script help me a lot,but the problem is that I want to write text in the center of the blank space.

Comment: Read the documentation and it will give you answers to a lot of these questions, that's why we write documentation.... in this case, you want to set horizontal alignment as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('Your lable');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
```